# Accessing a distant SQL server from ASP.NET/Web service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, vsto

I have VSTO application that needs to access a SQL server database but it cannot do it directly. I have thought of two ways to perform this task, but I don't know if those are the best ones :

- Creating a "fake" aspx that will be accessed from the VSTO and that will call the SQL server database
- Hosting a web service on my distant server. This web service will be accessed from the VSTO and will call the SQL server database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option is the way to go. Create a WCF service, and have this access the SQL Server in a trusted environment.  You can protect the service with Windows Authentication, or otherwise pass a user name/password or session key with every call.

Comment: Your advice remains the same if I use a MySQL database ?